# Drag & Drop from List to a drop area angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am implementing a drag and drop feature in angular where i want to drag an item from the list and place it anywhere in the drop zone area.

The position of the dragged item should be where I mousedrop it (leave the mouse pointer from dragged state). I tried using cdk drag-drop functionality from angular material ui but couldn't find a proper solution to my problem.

In the end I should get an absolute position of the dragged-dropped list item, relative to the drop zone.

Currently, i have referred to the plugins/libraries and in those i have only found the tranfering of items from one list to another.

Here's a diagram for the feature i want to achieve... [Drag and Drop Functionality Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QPYM.png)

Comment: add your code and if possible some screenshot as well, to get better understanding of what you want to achieve and what's wrong with your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you should try using the Dragula library, I have used it and is very user friendly and having so almost all features needed while dragging and dropping the element.

Here is the link you can refer to for detailed information:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that some city of rajasthan and other city from maharastra and these city in a another div when you drag and drop them it provide response

Comment: I am trying to drag the city from cities list and drop those within the dropzone anywhere i want